# open cart : Authorize .net payment module not visible under checkout even after installing module

Tags: php, ajax, opencart, prestashop

i am new to open cart :
i have added one product in my cart and trying to checkout with Authorize .net payment module but the thing is that Authorize .net payment option is not visible under checkout  even after installing module, but if i install pay pal or COD its visible,
 need some suggestion how to make it (Authorize .net payment option) visible under check out

thanks

Comment: remove prestashop tag from the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be any following reasons for any payment module is not visible in Opencart

1. You may not have filled all fields in extension.
2. May not enabled extension.
3. Using any custom theme.
4. Installed any extension through Ocmod.
5. installed any Extension through Vqmod.

let us see how to solve the above issues

1. First, fill all the required fields in Authorize.net extension and enable it and give an appropriate sort order.
2. if you are installed any extension for checkout page then please go to extension->modification then refresh page
3. If you are installed Vqmod then go to Vqmod/Vqcache and delete all the files.

Now go to your checkout page and refresh it mostly this fixes your problem.
If you are using custom theme then contact theme provider to solve the issue.

Hopes this answer might help you.

Comment: thank you @Ziauz 
as i was new that time i was not knowing, the module was disabled.